LC filter design
I'm trying to design a simple functioning LC filter.
My input signal is a square wave with a maximum value of 230 V, a minimum value of -230 V, and a frequency of 50 Hz.
I want to convert this to a sine wave with a maximum value of 230 V and a minimum value of -230 V at 50 Hz.
Firstly, I set the cut-off frequency to 50 Hz and observed that there are many combinations of L and C values that satisfy this.


Afterward, I used the following formula to determine the Q factor, but the problem is, what should the Q factor be? This is my first question.


When I hit a roadblock here, I tried something like this: I changed the L and C values in the simulation, aiming to achieve 0 dB at 50 Hz on the frequency response graph. It didn't quite reach exactly 0 dB, but I got a value very close to it. However, in the obtained result, I couldn't achieve a pure sine wave shape, and the Vmax and Vmin values were different.

What exactly am I doing wrong, and how can I obtain a filter that behaves as I described above?





You should set your resonant frequency higher than your 50 Hz operating frequency or you'll have problems. You have the wrong formula for Q factor because it's a parallel network you should consider. Is your input a square wave?

@ Andy aka, Yes, my input signal is a square wave.

I want to only retain the 50 Hz component and remove the 150 Hz and other odd components. In this case, what should be the cutoff frequency?

Your aim is an impossibility and setting the resonant frequency to 50 Hz will draw massive current to ground at 50 Hz and make the filter output very susceptible to load value changes. You need to re-read my first comment and reduce your expectations.


I used the following formula to determine the Q factor, but the
problem is, what should the Q factor be? This is my first question

That is the Q factor formula for a series LCR resonant circuit; your circuit is a parallel LCR circuit and, R and C appear in the numerator: -
$$Q_P = R\sqrt{\frac{C}{L}}$$
Link to RLC wiki page if you want to double check things.

I changed the L and C values in the simulation, aiming to achieve 0 dB
at 50 Hz on the frequency response graph. It didn't quite reach
exactly 0 dB, but I got a value very close to it. However, in the
obtained result, I couldn't achieve a pure sine wave shape, and the
Vmax and Vmin values were different.

Here's the detail of the 1st peak (colours changed to make it more legible): -

317 volts pk from a square wave pk of 250 volts (1.268:1) is within half a percent of theory.
Ask yourself about a square wave; what is the amplitude of the fundamental sinewave that is locked within? Does it have a fundamental sinewave that has an amplitude of 250 volts or, does it have a fundamental amplitude that is 1.273 (4 divided by \$\pi\$) bigger?

Image from Wolfram MathWorld. Look at the red fundamental waveform and think about it.
Maybe you are more interested in the Fourier transform of a square wave: -

You can see the 4/pi bit easily (mainly because I've highlighted it).

What exactly am I doing wrong

It went wrong for you because when you did an AC analysis you thought you could substitute a square-wave for the sinewave input and get the same answer.

and how can I obtain a filter that behaves as I described above?

Never but, you might be able to get something acceptable with a two stage LC filter and some hard work toiling at the simulator. Lower your expectations is my advice.

If you want to achieve pure sine wave shape, you need a filter that passes 50 Hz and blocks all other unwanted frequencies.
Your simple RC filter is only a second order filter, it has a slope you have already drawn, it won't block e.g. 100 Hz, or 150 Hz. For example 150 Hz is not even attenuated by 20 dB.
So single LC filter cannot simultaneously pass 50 Hz and block everything after it. There are no component values or cutoff frequency that can achieve what you want.
